# invalidAccessError: getDisplayMedia must be called from a user gesture handler - Safari

Tags: safari, screensharing, get-display-media

I get sharing screen by using mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() and it work well on Chrome and Safari < 15. But when I try it on Safari 15, I hit the bug:
invalidAccessError: getdisplaymedia must be called from a user gesture handler

I have viewed the answer: [Safari getDisplayMedia must be called from a user gesture handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929138/safari-getdisplaymedia-must-be-called-from-a-user-gesture-handler). They said that the reason is:

> This safari error occures due to the event (event that should trigger it) having isTrusted property false. This property is set automatically and is not possible to fake.

When I log event.isTrusted on Safari 15, its value is true. But I still hit the above error. Can you guys help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You try to enable the experimental feature "Enable MDNS Ice Candidates" in Safari settings, advanced, experimental features